# How to update files in solution

Tags: 2013

I have a solution of SharePoint 2013. It contains css, javascript, aspx and other files. I need to update this solution including updates to the files.
When I do update solution from console i don't see new version of those files. I just see old versions of files in SharePoint Designer.
How can I do an update solution with updates to included files as well?

Answer (score 0):

try to use feature upgrade - this is the official way to upgrade your files. Or do you have a problem with applying it?

Comment: I found examples of feature upgrading, but they relate an update of ContentType. Is there a way to update files with feature upgrade?

Comment: Try this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73338/provisioning-updating-modified-css-files-via-feature

Answer (score 0):

If by solution you mean you have a wsp already, then you need to install it and deploy it (and you may need to choose target web applications, depending what types of resources it contains).

We have often seen SharePoint cache old versions of both dlls and files, so if it can be managed, a reboot just after deployment is a good way to avoid that.